# Use HTML Agility Pack to extract dynamic content

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Let's say that I have a list of 10 news sources that I like to import into my local database. I need to open each of these external news pages, extract the main content, and save it. The html structure in all of these pages are different. Some use div, while other use article tags.

I know that I can use the HttpWebRequest object to open the page, and use HtmlAgilityPack to load the [HTML] document.

```cs
HttpWebRequest oReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)oReq.GetResponse();
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
```

However, I don't know how I could target the main element without knowing the type.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the news sites to see if they offer an API to get the data you want? Webscraping is generally frowned upon (i.e. not permitted) for sites like that.

Comment: An option might be (programmatically) look at other pages, find the element that has most text/or most changing text between pages, and target that element. It might get you somewhere closer to what you want, yet not perfect. If you are REALLY keen you could write a neural net and train it with MANY websites and validate them against the main content, but anyway, the first option is much easier to implement :)

Comment: Since news aggregation like http://www.bing.com/news or https://news.google.com/news was never done before this is clearly impossible. In addition designing such "impossible" system is way too broad for SO question - if you narrow down what you actually want to detect on a page it may become on-topic so.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Agility Pack is EXTREMELY useful, but the code using it generally has to be customized to the structure of the site.

You can try to be generic and adaptive, but even the "Big Boys" like Evernote have to have different clipping options for different site layouts.

The first thing I'd look at:  If it's news, should you be using their RSS feeds instead? (Not just technically, but legally.  Check out the sites' terms of service sections.)

If you have to go with parsing their site, I'd suggest making an interface and a separate class for each site that implements the interface.  Tweak each class to match the respective site's structure.

Comment: I like the idea of the creating an interface, and a separate class.